# Get List from JSON using Retrofit 2.1

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I'm trying  to get `JSON` and parse it to `ArrayList<Manager>` using Retrofit 2.1.

I created an interface with `GET` request and initialized Retrofit also.

Why `response.isSuccessful()` is false?

[JSON:](https://api.myjson.com/bins/xkyz)

```
  {
  "managers": 
[

    {"name": "John Smith", "plan": "100"},
    {"name": "Alex Sprite", "plan": "96"},
    {"name": "Den Bollom", "plan": "2"},
    {"name": "Jaromir Jagr", "plan": "68"},
    {"name": "Wane Gretzky", "plan": "99"},
    {"name": "Winsent Trade", "plan": "54"},
    {"name": "Paul Dagger", "plan": "30"},
    {"name": "Tommy Gun", "plan": "60"},
    {"name": "Luc Perry", "plan": "15"},
    {"name": "Tend Smarr", "plan": "64"}


   ] 

  }
```

**Interface ManagerAPI:**

```
public interface ManagerAPI {


    String URL = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/get/";



    @GET("xkyz.json")
    Call <List<Manager>> getManagers();

}
```

**POJO-Class:**

```
public class Manager {

    @SerializedName("managers")
    private ArrayList<Manager> managers;


    public ArrayList<Manager> getManagers() {
        return managers;
    }

    public void setManagers(ArrayList<Manager> managers) {
        this.managers = managers;
    }


    public Manager() {

    }

    String name;
    int plan;


    public Manager(String name, int plan) {
        this.name = name;
        this.plan = plan;
    }


    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPlan() {
        return plan;
    }
}
```

**InitRetrofit:**

```
private void requestData() {

    Retrofit retrofit = getRetrofit();
    ManagerAPI service = retrofit.create(ManagerAPI.class);
    Call<List<Manager>> call = service.getManagers();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Manager>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Manager>> call, Response<List<Manager>> response) {

            Log.e("OnResponce", "OK");
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                List<Manager>  managers = response.body();
            }
            else Log.e("Response", "Not ok");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Manager>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("OnFailure", "Fail");
        }
    });

}

@NonNull
private Retrofit getRetrofit() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ManagerAPI.URL)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
}
```

**LOG:**

```
07-13 20:43:34.762 5402-5402/ru.alexbykov.jsonexample E/OnResponce: OK
07-13 20:43:34.762 5402-5402/ru.alexbykov.jsonexample E/Response Successful?: NO
07-13 20:43:34.762 5402-5402/ru.alexbykov.jsonexample E/response.message: Not Found
07-13 20:43:34.762 5402-5402/ru.alexbykov.jsonexample E/response.message: 404
07-13 20:43:34.762 5402-5402/ru.alexbykov.jsonexample E/response.message: null
07-13 20:43:34.978 5402-5469/ru.alexbykov.jsonexample E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9fd21c0
```

Comment: Can you see your Log cat and paste it here ? Retrofit should tell you the errors

Comment: @nonews are you getting any errors?Or you are asking about how to use retrofit? Your question isn't clear to me.

Comment: @Soham 
My question was about operation after Retrofit initialization for reception  ArrayList<Manager>  as a result

Comment: @nonews You can check this sample from github https://github.com/sohambannerjee8/RetrofitSample_V_2.0.2

Comment: because your json is not an array.

Comment: how do you expect that part `{
  "managers": ` to be handled?

Comment: @Soham I approach the truth gradually. Now, it's unclear why `response.isSuccessful()`  is false.

Comment: @njzk2 What wrong with my JSON?
I want to get `ArrayList<Manager>` from this JSON. (One manager have a two attributes - name and plan).

Comment: an `ArrayList` needs to map to a ... list. you json is an object. It has to be mapped to an object.

Comment: @njzk2 How better to do in this situation? 
I thought the best way to get the desired objects - is to get an array with them..

Comment: the easier would be to change the json

Comment: @njzk2 Can you give an example of a valid JSON with multiple objects of the same type? and how correctly parce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so step 1, I would modify the JSON response to avoid extra complexity. That means removing the root element so it looks like the below.  We are left with a plain and simple array.

```
[
    {"name": "John Smith", "plan": "100"},
    {"name": "Alex Sprite", "plan": "96"},
    {"name": "Den Bollom", "plan": "2"},
    {"name": "Jaromir Jagr", "plan": "68"},
    {"name": "Wane Gretzky", "plan": "99"},
    {"name": "Winsent Trade", "plan": "54"},
    {"name": "Paul Dagger", "plan": "30"},
    {"name": "Tommy Gun", "plan": "60"},
    {"name": "Luc Perry", "plan": "15"},
    {"name": "Tend Smarr", "plan": "64"}
]
```

Step 2 Clean up your POJO.
You call the class `Manager`, but you include methods about including Lists of Managers inside said model.Sounds redundant and/or not intended. Drop these things below.

```
@SerializedName("managers")
private ArrayList<Manager> managers;


public ArrayList<Manager> getManagers() {
    return managers;
}

public void setManagers(ArrayList<Manager> managers) {
    this.managers = managers;
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer!
done. 

but still `response.isSuccessful()` is false..
new JSON:
https://api.myjson.com/bins/11p73

Comment: Okay please log `t.getMessage()` inside `onFailure` and post in here

Comment: Log is updated.
I have error in the `onResponse()` method. 

 `onFailure()` method is not called.

Comment: Yep sorry, please log `response.code(); response.message(); response.body()` in `onResponse`

Comment: Well there you go..it's a 404 error. Your host and path combined(https://api.myjson.com/bins/get/xkyz.json) are incorrect. The correct url appears to be https://api.myjson.com/bins/xkyz

Comment: Happy to help, retrofit is great